# Java Matcher.group(int) shows previous match values

Tags: java, regex

I wish to match complex numbers entered by a user in any of the following forms:

```
2+3i 2.2+3.4i .2+3.i .1i 3i 2. 5
```

The above input contains 7 complex numbers separated by spaces.

When the user inputs the following invalid expression like: `7+ 3.4i`

The complex number with a dangling `+` is considered to be invalid and hence not considered. Here, I wish to match only `3.4i`.

I obtain the output as follows:

```
Full match: 3.4i
Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: 3.4
Group 4: 7
```

I was surprised to see `7` matched in `Group 4` while it is not being displayed in `Full match`.

How can `7` be matched after `3.4`?
Shouldn't `Group 4` also display `null` similar to `Group 1` and `Group 2`?

Here is its implementation in Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.Scanner;

class simple
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        final String regex = "(?=[\\d.i])(\\d++\\.?+\\d*+|\\d*+\\.?+\\d++)?(?:\\+)(\\d++\\.?+\\d*+|\\d*+\\.?+\\d++)?+i(?=\\s|\\z)"+
                             "|(?=[\\d.i])(\\d++\\.?+\\d*+|\\d*+\\.?+\\d++)?(\\d++\\.?+\\d*+|\\d*+\\.?+\\d++)?+i?(?=\\s|\\z)";
        final String string = sc.nextLine();

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: In input remove spaces and make it `7+3.4i` and you'll see the desired order. However, the original problem remains.

Comment: What does the `7+` get parsed as in this case?

Comment: @fiveelements`7+3.4i` is a valid input. I wish to match only `3.4i` in the input `7+ 3.4i` where the user leaves a dangling `+`.

Comment: What you want in `7   +   3.4i` and `7  +   3.4   i`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisenThe regex fails to match `7+`.

Comment: @fiveelementsThe user is required to enter a complex number without spaces. In `7 + 3.4i` , the two complex numbers are obtained: `7` and `3.4i`. In `7 + 3.4 i`, three complex numbers are obtained: `7`, `3.4` and `i`.